# Error on running a PHP application from my Linux VM

Tags: php, ubuntu, virtual-machine, netbeans-8.2

I'm new to PHP and have this real basic issue that I'm not sure how to get around.

I have a 64 bit windows laptop with an Ubuntu VM.  I have installed netbeansIDE 8.2 for linux 64 bit from https://netbeans.org/downloads/index.html.

I can now create a new PHP project with all of the default settings.  But when I try to run it I get this message in the output console of netbeans:

> "/usr/bin/php" "-S" "localhost:8000"
>
> Notice: File could not be loaded: localhost:8000

I suspect it has to do with my Run Configuration of my project as shown below
[image]

In addition here's the output on Firefox when I try to run the php application.
[image]

But the internet is working on my firefox.

Here's some screenshots of the Netbeans - Options - PHP configurations I have:
[image]
[image]
Does anyone know how I can get it to run?

Comment: Nice screenshot :s

Comment: I know its horrible.  I couldn't screen shot the from linux VM to my windows host where I'm on stackoverflow.  So its an actual picture from my cell phone :(

Comment: SHouldn't your project URL be `http://localhost:8000`?

Comment: Everyone, I finally got the project to run.  In the Project Properties - Run Configuration.  I changed the "Run as" field from "Local Web Host ..." to "PHP Built-in Web Server".  With Hostname still "localhost" and Port being "8000".  Thanks for your help everyone!

Answer (score 1):

Please change your **Project URL**:

From :

```
https://localhost/8000
```

To:

```
https://localhost:8000
```